# Converting a troublesome JSON string to objects in Swift

Tags: json, swift, string, object

I have a string that I cannot get to convert to JSON.  I have tried JSONDecode, JSONSerialization, and everything else suggested on the first few pages of searches.  I also tried decoding it into encodable structs.

I thought there might be an issue with the fact that the data contains newline characters ("\r\n") so I also tried with removing those, and also with removing the whitespace (there is a lot, I wanted to make something nasty and non-printable wasn't in there).  The string is here, it is very long.

```
var rawData: String = "{\r\n    \"contacts\": [\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c200\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Ravi Tamada\",\r\n                \"email\": \"ravi@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"male\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c201\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Johnny Depp\",\r\n                \"email\": \"johnny_depp@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"male\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c202\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Leonardo Dicaprio\",\r\n                \"email\": \"leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"male\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c203\",\r\n                \"name\": \"John Wayne\",\r\n                \"email\": \"john_wayne@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"male\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c204\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Angelina Jolie\",\r\n                \"email\": \"angelina_jolie@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"female\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c205\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Dido\",\r\n                \"email\": \"dido@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"female\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c206\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Adele\",\r\n                \"email\": \"adele@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"female\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c207\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Hugh Jackman\",\r\n                \"email\": \"hugh_jackman@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"male\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c208\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Will Smith\",\r\n                \"email\": \"will_smith@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"male\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c209\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Clint Eastwood\",\r\n                \"email\": \"clint_eastwood@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"male\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c2010\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Barack Obama\",\r\n                \"email\": \"barack_obama@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"male\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c2011\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Kate Winslet\",\r\n                \"email\": \"kate_winslet@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"female\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n                \"id\": \"c2012\",\r\n                \"name\": \"Eminem\",\r\n                \"email\": \"eminem@gmail.com\",\r\n                \"address\": \"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country\",\r\n                \"gender\" : \"male\",\r\n                \"phone\": {\r\n                    \"mobile\": \"+91 0000000000\",\r\n                    \"home\": \"00 000000\",\r\n                    \"office\": \"00 000000\"\r\n                }\r\n        }\r\n    ]\r\n}"
```

The string is just demo data from [here](https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/)

Any ideas, thoughts, or working samples would be great.  I know this is a common sounding question, but having tried almost everything I still can't get it working.

Comment: I don't understand, doing `let rawDataData = rawData.data(using: .utf8); let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: rawDataData!, options: [])` just worked for me (got a dictionary). So what's your issue currently? What do you want at the end? Could you show your struct/final objects?

Comment: That worked.  Sorry for the silly question, I tried this method before and got nil.  I must had have a typo.  If you post this as an answer I will accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: If this worked, Codable should too. There are plenty of question about JSON Serialization, so find a duplicate question and mark it as such, or delete it because there are so many and you might have done a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONDecoder` doesn't care about whitespaces or newlines as long as it is well-formed JSON. Think about how your model should be like, rather than worrying about new line characters.

From a quick look at the JSON, I created these model structs:

```
struct Phone : Codable {
    let mobile: String
    let home: String
    let office: String
}

struct Contact : Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let address: String
    let gender: String
    let phone: Phone
}

struct Contacts : Codable {
    let contacts: [Contact]
}
```

And you just need to decode a `Contacts` object like this:

```
let json = try! Data.init(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/")!)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let contacts = try! decoder.decode(Contacts.self, from: json)
```

One possible reason you are unable to decode it might be that you made a mistake when you copied the JSON string and making it single line. As you can see here, I used `Data.init(contentsOf:)` to get the data. This is much more reliable than copy and pasting the string yourself.

Also note that there are multiline string literals in Swift:

```
let jsonString = """
your multiline JSON can go here...
"""
```

Comment: The answer in the comment worked, but this is how I wanted to do it, and when I tried it didn't work for some odd reason.  I did make the string a single line.  Great advice.